# How to copy files from phone to cloud in ES File Explorer

Tags: es-file-explorer

I use ES File Explorer and I really like it. I added my Google Drive accounts to it and I can download files from them.

However, when I want to upload my images and I select them and press Copy to, it shows 2 tabs: Local and Net. On the Net tab, I see nothing. How could I select my cloud drives to upload files to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can that following these steps:

- Select the image(s) you want to upload
- Click on "copy", it's in the lower bar, at left
- In another tab, open the folder where you want to upload your image(s)
- Click on the clipoard icon at left
- Click on "paste all"

Comment: Yes, it works. I also have a solution, I share that, too.

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of selecting the Pictures folder, you have to select the corresponding DCIM folder
- Select the images
- Instead of Copy, select the Other options menu in the right corner
- Select Copy To from that menu
- A different browser dialog will appear where you can select the cloud storages as well